# Can I gain access to a Gmail account on my computer if I can only access it on my phone?

Tags: gmail, account-recovery

I recently left a university that uses a Gmail interface for its email accounts and have subsequently lost access through the university's site. However I had synced the account with the Gmail app on my phone and can still access the account through it. Is there any way I can regain access to the account through the regular Gmail web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. We also use the Gmail interface (it's called G suite) for use within our organization.

After you leave the organization, ideally they would delete your account as well. If you have accepted the terms of use when configuring it the first time, they would also be able to remotely delete any data that might be associated with your account. I suggest that you take a backup of things if you have access and forget about the account.

FYI: they have to pay a monthly fee to keep your account on G suite as well.